# Recursive Mergesort on LinkedList

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, linked-list, mergesort

I've been getting headaches trying to implement a recursive mergesort but I keep getting problem after problem.
Right now, I have a lot of trouble when adding elements which has caused 75% of my problems earlier.
This is the code of the implementation, the main problem is the merge part:

```
 static public void DoMerge(LinkedList <Contacto> L, int left, int mid, int right)
 {
     LinkedList <Contacto> temp = new LinkedList <Contacto>();
   int i, left_end, num_elements, tmp_pos, comp;

   left_end = (mid - 1);
   tmp_pos = left;
   num_elements = (right - left + 1);

   while ((left <= left_end) && (mid <= right))
   {
       comp= L.get(left).get_name().compareTo(L.get(mid).get_name());
       if (comp<=0)
       temp.add(tmp_pos++,L.get(left++));
       else
       temp.add(tmp_pos++,L.get(mid++));
   }

   while (left <= left_end)
    temp.add(tmp_pos++,L.get(left++));

   while (mid <= right)
    temp.add(tmp_pos++,L.get(mid++));

   for (i = 0; i < num_elements; i++)
   {
       L.set(right, temp.get(right));
       right--;
   }

}static public void MergeSort_Recursive(LinkedList <Contacto> L, int left, int right)
{
 int mid; 
if (right > left)
 {
   mid = (right + left) / 2;
   MergeSort_Recursive(L, left, mid);
   MergeSort_Recursive(L, (mid + 1), right);
   DoMerge(L, left, (mid+1), right);
 }
}
```

The main problem again is the merge part which is constantly troubling me, specially adding the elements to the temporary list. The compiler throws me an out of bounds exception.

Comment: Why don't you just use Collections.sort()?

Comment: If you're sorting a linked list, you really shouldn't be using `get`. It'll ruin your performance. You probably want to get an Iterator with the `iterator` method and use that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
LinkedList <Contacto> temp = new LinkedList <Contacto>();
```

You initialized an empty list. But, this line:

```
temp.add(tmp_pos++,L.get(left++));
```

You insert an Object to index `tmp_pos` which can be larger than the current size of temp (first, size of `temp` is zero). (Read more about [add.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#add%28int,%20E%29))

You can fix this by understanding that, for merge sort, `temp` actually is used as a stack, so this part is not necessary  `temp.add(tmp_pos++,L.get(left++));`, use `temp.add(L.get(left++));` instead. (Replace other statements in similar manner).

And for the last part, just use

```
 for (i = 0; i < num_elements; i++)
 {
       L.set(right, temp.removeLast());
       right--;
 }
```

Comment: It's true. I had actually some doubts regarding add, so I thought if I gave it an index highed than the list size it would simply add it as the last element.

Well after making add just add to the end I also switched the last part to remove and get the last element.

However the index keeps getting higher than the list, in the part of the code in which I compare the two strings. I tried modifiying the conditional for the while but raised more problems so I left it like that.

The problems mostly it seems it is tha the index ends up being the list size for the comparation indexes.

Comment: @Auraldo Hmm, I cannot understand your point, but you can always print out the index of left and mid to check :) this will help a lot for your debugging.